# How do I put a <div> box around my cursor on click?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying re-create the facebook tagging functionality, where you click on an image and the part of the image you click on displays an empty box (or a square).

Using jQuery, how do I make the box appear around my cursor on the click?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly code warning:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image-wrapper").click(function(e){
      var ele = $("<div>");
      ele.css({width:"50px", height:"50px", border:"1px solid green", position:"absolute", left: e.pageX - 25, top: e.pageY -25});
      $("body").append(ele);      
   }); 
  });
</script>

<div id="image-wrapper" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 300px; height: 200px;">
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. It ALMOST does exactly what I want, if I combine it with the above two, I will be able to achieve exactly what I am trying to.

Thanks...this is awesome!

Comment: Hey Kevin,
        This one has proved to be the most efficient for me. The issue is that with every box click, the box stays on the image. How do I adjust it so that the box comes off when I click elsewhere?

i.e. if I click in 10 different places, the only place I see the box is in the last clicked position...I am not seeing 9 - 10 boxes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be able to help you, where "image" is the class of image that is taggable and "box" is the ID of an absolutely position element:

```
$(".image").click(function(e){
    $("#box").css('top',e.pageY).css('left',e.pageY);   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If you don't mind me asking, where can I find info on this e.pageY element? What is that called? Is that a CSS element or jQuery element?

Thanks.

Comment: @marcamillion It's called an event object, it's pretty useful and you can get more info on it here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $(document).click(function(e){
    $("<div>").
      text("Foo").
      css({ position: "absolute", top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX }).
      appendTo(document.body);
  });
});
```

You can find more information about jQuery event objects in their docs for [events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). In this example, I am using [event.Page](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/)X and [event.PageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/).

Comment: Thanks Raul. It seems that Sam152 beat you to it, but this definitely helps me with my issue. Do you happen to know where I can go to learn more about the 'e.Page' elements that you used here? What are they called and how do I even Google them? I want to make sure I am using them correctly, and don't want to just copy/paste without understanding :)

Thanks.

Comment: @marcamillion I update my answer to include references to the jQuery event documentation.